# How to Read XML attribute?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, xml, elements-xml

I have XMl file that has various file attachments when the attachment is empty the xsi:nil="true" will be set so i want to read this attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value-of` to retrieve value in xslt.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="nil" />
```

For more information on Setting and Getting value in XSLT, [click here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/02/07/trxml9.html)

Comment: I want to use the attribute in c# programming to validate my requirement could help to read this attribute in C#